# obtener strigValue json

Tags: java, json

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de obtener unos datos de un json, pero cuando los imprimo , me salen asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
for(SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()){
        JSONObject jsonResponseObjectMain = new JSONObject(msg.getMessageAttributes());
        String idControl = jsonResponseObjectMain.getString("idControl");
        String idConvenio = jsonResponseObjectMain.getString("idConvenio");
        System.out.println("------idControl-------" + idControl);
        System.out.println("------idConvenio-------" + idConvenio);
}
```

Comment: La salida es totalmente normal, que es lo que esperas obtener? Esperas obtener solo un elemento del objeto? (ej: `stringValue`) Es muy probable que idConvenio no sea un String propiamente tal

Comment: asi es, como puedo obtenerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basandose en la salida, es probable que `idConvenio` e `idControl` no sean `String` propiamente tal, sino un `JSONObject`, por lo que deberia ser un poco mas elaborado:

```
JSONObject jsonResponseObjectMain = new JSONObject(msg.getMessageAttributes());
String idControl = jsonResponseObjectMain.getJSONObject("idControl").getString("stringValue");;
String idConvenio = jsonResponseObjectMain.getJSONObject("idConvenio").getString("stringValue");
System.out.println("------idControl-------" + idControl);
System.out.println("------idConvenio-------" + idConvenio);
```